# Difference between inheriting from object and object.__class__ for python?

Tags: python

I can see code below

```
class MetaStrategy(StrategyBase.__class__): pass
```

I am not sure why not just write code like below

```
class MetaStrategy(StrategyBase): pass
```

Definition schematic

```
class StrategyBase(DataAccessor):
    pass

class DataAccessor(LineIterator):
    pass

class LineIterator(with_metaclass(MetaLineIterator, LineSeries)):
    pass

def with_metaclass(meta, *bases):
    class metaclass(meta):
        def __new__(cls, name, this_bases, d):
            return meta(name, bases, d)
    return type.__new__(metaclass, str('temporary_class'), (), {})
```

Comment: those would do two completely different things. The first inherits from the *class* of `StrategyBase`, which itself is presumably a class, and `__call__` is either `type` or another metaclass. `MetaStrategy` would inherit from `StrategyBse`

Comment: `StrategyBase.__class__` is `StrategyBase`'s metaclass, which is entirely different from the class `StrategyBase` itself.

Comment: First the user-defined classes extends Object class by default. Also Object class implements a set of methods and variables which are common to all the objects being created in the application. This is the main reason why we have Object class as a base class for all the other classes. So in your case, the inheritance will be either direct or indirect.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `self.__class__` from a subclass instance, `self.__class__` will use that type of the subclass.

Any class that is expressly specified while using the class will be used naturally.

Take the example below:

```
class Foo(object):
    def create_new(self):
        return self.__class__()

    def create_new2(self):
        return Foo()

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

b = Bar()
c = b.create_new()
print type(c)  # We got an instance of Bar
d = b.create_new2()
print type(d)  # we got an instance of Foo
```